# Read more read less with wrap/unwrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, show-hide

I am trying to make a 'read-more read-less' with a wrap method but it only works for show more.
So basically if the text is longer than I need it to be I strip it and add a *read-more-link* (that works). After it is unstripped I add a *read-less-link* that is supposed to strip it to its previous length so it can be unstripped again with the *read-more-link* but wrap doesn't work here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxLength = 490;
  $(".keimeno").each(function() {
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if ($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
      var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
      var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
      $(this).empty().html(newStr);
      $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">...read more</a>');
      $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + ' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-less">read less</a>' + '</span>');
    }
  });
  
  $(".read-more").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
    $(this).remove();
  });
  
  $(".read-less").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().wrap();
  });
});
```

```css
.keimeno .more-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spicy+Rice&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="card">
  <ul id="kirio">
    <li>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class="keimeno">
          SOME TEXT asdasdas SOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME
          TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE
          TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MORE
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class="keimeno">
          SOME TEXT asdasdas SOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME
          TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME
          TEXT asdasdas
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9nsmyvu/1/***

Comment: See **_https://jsfiddle.net/4urow9cL/9/_** for OP's original code.

Comment: You had a faulty `</div>` in your original code, between the second `<li>` and `<div class="col-lg-12">`. I removed it because it didn't directly pertain to the problem. But you should be aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function out of the text manipulaton that you do on `$(document).ready();` and call that function when "read less" is clicked. Also note that it's necessary to delegate the `click()` events for "read more" and "read less" from a static parent element like `document` as both are added dynamically to the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function readMore() {
    var maxLength = 490;
    $(".keimeno").each(function() {
      var myStr = $(this).text();
      if ($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
        var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
        var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
        $(this).empty().html(newStr);
        $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">...read more</a>');
        $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + ' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-less">read less</a>' + '</span>');
      }
    });

  }
  readMore();
  $(document).on("click", ".read-more", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
    $(this).remove();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".read-less", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    readMore();
  });
});
```

```css
.keimeno .more-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <ul id="kirio">
    <li>

      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class="keimeno">
          SOME TEXT asdasdas SOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME
          TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE
          TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MOREOME TEXT MORE TEXT MORE
        </p>
      </div>



    </li>
    <li>

      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class="keimeno">
          SOME TEXT asdasdas SOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME
          TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME TEXT asdasdasSOME
          TEXT asdasdas
        </p>
      </div>


    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @GeoPap Glad that I was able to help. If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer so your question is resolved as answered/solved.